# label and value overlapping in material design with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, material-design

I'm using mdb in my ember app. I'm generating dynamic value for the input field. In the UI value and label are getting overlapped. How to deal with it?

```
<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-user-o prefix grey-text iconSize"></i>
    {{input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" value=model.firstName}}
    <label for="firstName">First Name<i class="mandatoryIcon">*</i></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
didInsertElement() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  if (this.get('model.firstName') !== null) {
    Ember.$('firstName').focus();
  }
}
```

You can always use the autofocus attribute as well

```
{{input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" value=model.firstName autofocus=true}}
```